# Is Zorn's lemma required to prove the existence of a maximal atlas on a manifold?

Tags: manifolds, axiom-of-choice

In the definition of smooth manifolds, complex manifolds, and similar constructions, one starts by defining a property on neighborhoods in the space, specifying how they relate on overlapping neighborhoods. An atlas is a set of such neighborhoods that covers the space. Some books (Lee, Warner) define the structure as the maximal atlas. Others define it as the equivalence class of compatible atlases.

I was under the impression that the advantage of using the equivalence class definition instead of the maximal atlas definition was that the proof of the existence of such a maximal atlas requires Zorn's lemma, which some prefer not to use if not absolutely necessary.

But Lee and Warner's books both contain existence proofs for this maximal atlas; they start with any atlas, and then just take the set of all compatible charts. If that argument somehow relies on Zorn's lemma (or some other variant of choice), I can't see how. So what do you say? Is choice required, assumed for convenience but not required, or just not necessary at all?

Comment: I did find this thread 

http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/43187/why-maximal-atlas

where a Mariano Suárez-Alvarez states without justification that Zorn's lemma is not required.

Comment: It seems clear to me that Zorn's Lemma is **not** required.

Comment: You think Mariano's answer does not provide justification?  Maybe you should justify that claim (sorry...): I found it quite convincing.  The point is that in this case there is not just a maximal element in the poset of atlases, there is a *unique* maximal atlas containing any given one: as you say, you just take the set of all compatible charts.  At what point are we *choosing* anything?

Comment: By the way, as far as this site is concerned, one should speak of *the* Mariano Suárez-Alvarez, not *a* Mariano Suárez-Alvarez.  More generally, although I would have to believe that there other other Mariano Suárez-Alvarez's living on Earth, in the mathematical world to the best of my knowledge there is only one...

Comment: I agree with you, @PeteL.Clark, that this construction of a maximal atlas doesn't choose anything at any point, and doesn't seem to rest on Zorn's lemma. So then my question is, why are there so many sources which seem to require it? Google "maximal atlas" "zorn's lemma", to see what I mean. For example, these lecture notes from a course at MIT:

http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-965-geometry-of-manifolds-fall-2004/lecture-notes/lecture1.pdf

Comment: @ziggurism: well, that's a more than fair question.  But I suspect that to answer it you'll have to ask someone who appeals to Zorn's Lemma...

Comment: ... My best guess is that someone(s) wrote it at one point and then many later authors have continued to write it without really thinking things through.  As you can see in my answer to the linked question, this whole business of maximal atlases really has nothing to do with geometry of any kind, and a geometer will know this and probably instinctively not think too much about it.  For instance the notes you link to are written by one of the world's leading geometers.  But I am rather confident that he doesn't know more about maximal atlases than I do...what is there to know?

Comment: Despite not having deep knowledge in the question's details, I have two points to add to this short discussion: (1) It is completely fine to assume the axiom of choice nowadays. Just as much as you assume that the real numbers have a power set. The controversy about the axiom of choice is long gone. (2) To develop analysis you need some amount of choice. The larger the cardinality of the spaces you have, the more choice you are going to need to have **other things** behave as you would have wanted. Zorn's lemma can be replaced by a reduced form to match that amount of choice used to begin with

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Zorn's lemma is not required to prove the existence of a maximal atlas, though it is convenient. For one thing, we don't have to prove that compatibility of atlases is an equivalence relation. On the other hand, the obvious proof using Zorn's lemma requires some extra work to show that there is a *unique* maximal atlas containing any atlas. So let's do it without Zorn's lemma.

**Definition.** Two atlases on a manifold are compatible if their union is an atlas.

**Lemma.** Compatibility of atlases is an equivalence relation.

*Proof.* It is clear that compatibility is symmetric and reflexive, and it remains to be shown that compatibility is transitive. Let $\mathcal{A}_1, \mathcal{A}_2, \mathcal{A}_3$ be three atlases on a $k$-manifold $M$, and suppose $\mathcal{A}_1 \cup \mathcal{A}_2$ and $\mathcal{A}_2 \cup \mathcal{A}_3$ are atlases. We wish to show $\mathcal{A}_1 \cup \mathcal{A}_3$ is an atlas. So let $\varphi_1 : U_1 \to \mathbb{R}^k$ be a chart in $\mathcal{A}_1$, $\varphi_3 : U_3 \to \mathbb{R}^k$ be a chart in $\mathcal{A}_3$. $\mathcal{A}_2$ is an atlas, so for each point $x$ in $U_1 \cap U_3$ there is a chart $\varphi_2 : U_2 \to \mathbb{R}^k$ in $\mathcal{A}_2$ such that $x \in U_2$; but $\varphi_1$ and $\varphi_2$ are compatible and $\varphi_2$ and $\varphi_3$ are compatible so we see that $\varphi_1$ and $\varphi_3$ are locally compatible at $x$. (Here, ‘compatible’ means that the transition map satisfies the relevant regularity condition. There may well be invocations of the axiom of choice hidden here, but I will assume that there are not.) Moreover, $x$ is arbitrary in $U_1 \cap U_3$ so this shows $\varphi_1$ and $\varphi_3$ are compatible; and $\varphi_1$ and $\varphi_3$ are also arbitrary, so $\mathcal{A}_1 \cup \mathcal{A}_3$ is an atlas.

**Lemma.** The class of atlases on a manifold is a set.

*Proof.* The class of atlases is a subclass of the set
$$\mathscr{P} \left( \bigcup_{U \in \mathscr{P}(M)} \{ U \to \mathbb{R}^k \} \right)$$
where $\{ U \to \mathbb{R}^k \}$ denotes the set of all functions $U \to \mathbb{R}^k$, so by the axiom of separation,  the class of atlases is a set.

**Lemma.** The union of arbitrarily many pairwise compatible atlases is an atlas.

*Proof.* Immediate.

**Theorem.** Every atlas is contained in a unique maximal atlas.

*Proof.* From the above, it is clear that every atlas $\mathcal{A}$ is contained in some equivalence class of atlases, and this equivalence class is a set of compatible atlases. Let $\overline{\mathcal{A}}$ be the union of all those atlases. Then $\mathcal{A} \subseteq \overline{\mathcal{A}}$, and $\overline{\mathcal{A}}$ is the unique maximal atlas containing $\mathcal{A}$: for if $\mathcal{A} \subseteq \mathcal{A}'$, then $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{A}'$ are compatible, so $\mathcal{A}' \subseteq \overline{\mathcal{A}}$ by construction.

---

For the sake of completeness I sketch a proof using Zorn's lemma.

**Theorem.** Every atlas is contained in a maximal atlas.

*Proof.* The set of all atlases containing $\mathcal{A}$ partially ordered by inclusion is a chain-complete poset: indeed, it is clear that if we have a chain $\{ \mathcal{A}_\alpha \}$, then $\bigcup_\alpha \mathcal{A}_\alpha$ is also an atlas. Thus, the hypotheses of Zorn's lemma are satisfied and there is some maximal atlas containing $\mathcal{A}$.

Comment: Hi Zhen Lin. Thank you for that very detailed response.

So AC is convenient, but not required. When Lee and Warner wave their hands and say "just take the set containing all compatible charts", they don't mention equivalence relations. Actually, Lee says something along the lines of "we could use an equivalence relation, but let's not". 

How much are they allowed to skip? Do you think it's rigorous to skip the equivalence relation stuff, and also skip Zorn's lemma? I guess the tradeoff is that you don't get uniqueness, is that right?

Comment: @ziggurism: I don't think it's entirely legitimate to skip the transitivity proof. There's no a priori reason why the set of all atlases compatible with $\mathcal{A}$ should be a set of pairwise compatible atlases; but once we establish that they are all pairwise compatible, we can just take the union of them. Perhaps what's more important is establishing that there is in fact a _set_ of atlases to take the union of: the axioms of ZF do not permit us to take a class-indexed union.

Comment: @ZhenLin what is axiom of seperation and how it is used here? teach me please.

Comment: It is the first time I see in writing a proof that compatibility of atlases is transitive (while compatibility of charts is *not* transitive). Congratulations for your sense of rigor, Zhen!

Comment: @Flute The [axiom of separation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_schema_of_specification) is an axiom (schema) of Zermelo–Fraenkel set theory, and you've probably been using it all along without realising it!

Comment: @ZhenLin, I really do not understand the statement and some symbols also, could you tell me in short what is the main idea or the statement?\

Comment: @Flute It isn't very important. Roughly speaking, if you can describe a subclass of a _set_ by writing down a logical formula that its members, then that subclass is also a set.

Comment: @ZhenLin Hi Zhen Lin, I have a question about your proof using the Zorn's Lemma, that is , you choosed the $\bigcup_\alpha \mathcal{A}_\alpha$ as the upper bound of the chain . However, If for any chain $\{U_k\}$,can we choose $\bigcup_k U_k$ as the chain's upper bound ? Or we will prove every poset has a maximal element.

Comment: @AlexanderLau : It's necessary to prove that $\bigcup_kU_k$ is also a member of the poset (in this case, that it's an atlas). So Zorn's Lemma proves that if you make a set $\mathcal U$ of sets into a poset under inclusion, then it has a maximal element *if* the union of any chain from $\mathcal U$ also belongs to $\mathcal U$. This statement is usually considered an early version of Zorn's Lemma, as Kuratowski proved it from first principles a decade before Zorn stated his lemma, and it's relatively easy to prove Zorn's version from Kuratowski's. But notice the ‘if’.

Comment: @ZhenLin : You can skip the transitivity proof because you jumped to the set of all *charts* compatible with the original atlas. No other *atlases* are considered, so no equivalence relation; and it's obviously a set (not a proper class) since it's a set of partial functions from one fixed set (the set of points) to another ($\mathbb R^n$), such as people form all the time. This doesn't mean that you really skip the hard part of the proof; you have to prove that this set of charts is an atlas, which takes about the same amount of work. But you didn't have to use an equivalence relation.