# Complex atlas and Zorn's lemma, maximal complex atlas

Tags: riemann-surfaces, complex-geometry

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is Zorn's lemma required to prove the existence of a maximal atlas on a manifold?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/66554/is-zorns-lemma-required-to-prove-the-existence-of-a-maximal-atlas-on-a-manifold)

Could any one explain me in detail how to prove the following statements in rigorous way?

> Two complex atlases are equivalent iff their union is also a complex atlas. An easy Zorn's lemma argument will show that every complex atlas is contained in a *unique* maximal complex atlas. Moreover, two atlases are equivalent iff they are contained in the same maximal complex atlas.

How to show that any atlas on $X$ determines a unique complex structure?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/66554/is-zorns-lemma-required-to-prove-the-existence-of-a-maximal-atlas-on-a-manifold

Comment: ah! I should have checked before, Thank you @AsafKaragila